# Cannot build project with restkit 0.20

Tags: xcode, macos, restkit

I have a project for OS X which uses RestKit (installed as git submodule). Yesterday I updated the RestKit submodule and I found out the use of AFNetworking (so I have to change some of my code which used RKClient).

The problem is that I cannot build my project anymore. I have to migrate my code yet, but the error is

> RestKit.framework/Headers/RKHTTPRequestOperation.h:21:9: fatal error: 'AFNetworking.h' file not found
>
> `#import "AFNetworking.h"`

If I open only the RestKit project, then the framework is successfully built, but the first time I include it (with `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`) the above error appears!

BTW: doing in my RestKit folder `git pull origin master` updates the module, but did not downloaded the AFNetworking files.. I manually copy the files in the folder. Am I missing something in the update procedure?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing RestKit through CocoaPods...

(the accepted answer given in [RestKit and AFNetworking build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754547/restkit-and-afnetworking-build-error/13762665) did not worked for me.. but the advice to install cocoapods yes)

Comment: this is not a good answer to this question. I have the same issue, I don't want to use CocoaPods. I know that CocoaPods track dependencies and will grab AFNetworking for you but your answer does not address why the problem occurs and a general case for fixing it.

Comment: I'm sorry... I lost 3 days trying to solve this, and the only way to continue working was to switch to CocoaPods....

Comment: answered here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754547/restkit-and-afnetworking-build-error/13762665#13762665

Answer (score 2):

cd into RestKit directory, and then do

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

That will pull the necessary AFNetworking files. Then rebuild.

Comment: Files are present on the file system and in the project. Simply it does not build. BTW, cmc + click on the header file opens the correct file, to Xcode sees it!