# RestKit and AFNetworking build error

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking

When I attempt to import the RestKit api into a project I get the following error:

```
  /Documents/Code/RestTest/RestKit/Code/Network/RKHTTPRequestOperation.h:21:9:
 'AFNetworking.h' file not found
```

I have installed RestKit as a git submodule, how do I resolve RestKit's dependency on AFNetworking?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Once cloned, simply do in the RestKit directory:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This will pull the AFNetworking version RestKit needs

Answer (score 3):

If you use CocoaPods will do all this automaticaly.

From RestKit install docs:

> ### Install CocoaPods if not already available:
>
> > $ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
> >     $ pod setup
>
> Edit your Podfile and add RestKit:
>
> > $ edit Podfile
> >     platform :ios, '5.0'
> >     pod 'RestKit', :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git', :branch => 'development'
>
> ### Testing and Search are optional components
>
> > pod 'RestKit/Testing',  :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git', :branch => 'development'
> >     pod 'RestKit/Search',  :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git', :branch => 'development'
> >
> > ### Install into your project:
> >
> > $ pod install
>
> Please note that if your installation fails, it may be because you are installing with a version of Git lower than CocoaPods is expecting. Please ensure that you are running Git >= 1.8.0 by executing git --version. You can get a full picture of the installation details by executing pod install --verbose.

Answer (score 0):

This might help some people. I completely skipped this section in the RestKit wiki specifically aimed at avoiding AFNetworking errors:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule#updating-the-precompiled-header-file

I had an `'AFNetworking.h' file not found` error and it was because I missed these imports in the .pch.